# iOS-Mobile Number validation based on Country

Tags: swift, xcode, libphonenumber

I have been working on iOS project where the requirement is validate international mobile number based on country code. I have used the [phonenumberkit iOS library](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) but I cannot validate mobile number using following code .

```
static func validatePhoneNumber(cellPhone:String,countryCode:String,countryName:String)->Bool{
    let finalResult = "+" + countryCode + cellPhone
    let formattedBasedOnCountryCode = PartialFormatter().formatPartial(finalResult)
    let result = self.parseNumber(formattedBasedOnCountryCode,countryName: countryName.uppercased())
    if result.stringByRemovingWhitespacesAndNewLines.characters.count > 1 {
        return true
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}
class func parseNumber(_ number: String,countryName:String) ->String {

    let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()
    do {
        let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse(number, withRegion: countryName, ignoreType: true)
        let result = phoneNumberKit.format(phoneNumber, toType: .international, withPrefix: false)
       // print("resulted phone number = \(result)")
        return result
    }
    catch {
        //print("Something went wrong = \(number) and countryName = \(countryName)")
        return ""
    }
    return ""
}
```

the above method work perfectly for UnitedState region only. for United Kingdom it doesn't validate the required number of digit.

> input 1: Country Code  = +1, Mobile Number = 2025550192, CountryName =
>   "US",  Result = Pass (even if I delete last digit, it validate
>   correctly)
>
> input 2:  Country Code  = +44, Mobile Number = 77009002, CountryName =
>   "GB",  Result = PASS. the actual number is 7700900243 it doesn't
>   validate. it always return as valid mobile number

Comment: you should get `false` with: `770090`

Comment: but it returns true